# Examples of p-orderings and p-sequences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This [paper here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5299.pdf) starts by introducing the title objects. These seem pretty basic but also interesting, but I am not really sure how to create some examples accurately. Would somebody be able to give some examples in integers of a p-ordering of a set of integers, say a p-ordering of a residue set of a small prime, with p as 2 or 3? And the p-sequence of the same set?